# bufferTime on OSMF

Tags: actionscript-3, buffering, osmf

I am having an issue with OSMF. I have an MP4 that is 40MB. It is being progressively loaded. My issue is the video wont begin playing until the video has fully loaded. I am testing this on a web server. Any idea what's going on or what I am not doing?

```
var mps:MediaPlayerSprite   = new MediaPlayerSprite();
mps.x                       = 159;
mps.y                       = 53;
mps.width                   = 512;
mps.height                  = 288;
mps.resource                = new URLResource("resources/video/3.4.1.mp4"); 
addChild(mps);
```

I've even tried adding `mps.mediaPlayer.bufferTime = 1;` but no luck. I've even tried 0.

Comment: well, I tried playing an FLV and it buffers correctly. There must be an issue with the MP4 encode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's right. It's an encoding issue. Even i had the same problem. Running the MP4 FastStart script on the video file fixes this. 
http://www.datagoround.com/lab/

Comment: yep, that fixed it. It'd be nice to know how that program works